# flowplayer video not playing in tablet

Tags: android, flowplayer

I am using flowplayer for video's playing in my application.

Everything is working fine with flowplayer video in all major browsers but the problem comes when i am running it in tablet ,it is always loading,no video get started (not playing) .

Can anyone tell me what is the problem ,

the code i am using is

```
var video = "http://stream.flowplayer.org/white/470x250.webm",api; 
            $("#id").flowplayer
            ({
                splash: true,
                playlist: [
                             [
                                {mp4: video},{webm: video},{ogg: video}
                             ]
                          ]
            }); 
         api = $("#id").data("flowplayer"); 
         api.play(0);
```

Is there anything i need to add to play the video in samsung tablet.

I will be very thankful for your help.

Thankyou.

Comment: Which product are you using? flowplayer HTML5 or flowplayer flash.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ...i am using flowplayer html5

Answer (score 0):

Check which browser you are using and the version to see if it supports `WebM`.  If not you will need to add an `MP4` video as well.

[Can I use WebM](http://caniuse.com/webm)

Answer (score 0):

Most tablets and phones *can* play MP4s also. They just need to be encoded using a lower compression. I.e. If you use level 3.0 when encoding, that's usually playable.

Also, is your video inside a password protected area? If it is, include the username and password into the video URL. Like this;
http://user:password@mydomain.com/members/video.mp4